why don't use index in this condition on mysql?
1 create table tb1
create table tb1 (t1 int not null, t2 varchar(20) not null);

2. add index for t1, t2
CREATE  INDEX index_t1 ON tb1(t1);
CREATE  INDEX index_t2 ON tb1(t2);

3. use explain test index
3.1 explain select * from tb1 where t1 = 1\G

3.2 explain select * from tb1 where t1 = '1'\G

3.3 explain select * from tb1 where t2 = '1'\G

3.4 explain select * from tb1 where t2 = 1\G


t1 is int, 1 is int, so 3.1 could use index
t1 is int, '1' is string, but 3.2 could use index, too
t2 is string, '1' is string, so 3.3 could use index
t2 is string, 1 is int, 3.4 couldn't use index

why 3.1 counld use index, 3.4 not.

integer to string is a one-to-one conversion. String to integer is an undefined conversion.

why 3.1 counld use index, 3.4 not. Because in this condition the column value must be converted to numeric value, and by fact you execute where CAST(t2 AS BIGINT) = 1. The expression does not match the index expression, hence the index cannot be used. PS. Pay attention to the key_len difference in 3.1 and 3.2. Try to understand the source of it, this is interesting...

There are several strings that can convert to the given value. Added to that is the fact that MySQL will convert any string that doesn't start with a numeric value to 0. So MySQL cannot use index when comparing a string column with a number. This is explained in MySQL documentation.
